# Keeping SVG as it is in Word document

Tags: xml, svg, ms-word, openxml

Further analysis of word document as XML files shows that when SVG image is inserted in the document it is converted to png so is there a way to keep the SVG extension as it is?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Please post your query at http://answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: I posted the question here because I thought that it can be done programmatically via XML @JohnKorchok

Comment: XML is not a programming language. In any case, we're not here to write code for you or to teach you how to write code. Please post again when you have a working program that needs debugging. BTW, your assumption that the SVG is converted to PNG is false. The original SVG is retained and a PNG copy is made for backwards compatibility with older versions of Word.

Comment: @AhmedMoustafa - the type definition for SVG parts (either as an image or XML) has not become available yet - see: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/204